# SpringBoot + MongoDB ReactiveRepository creates too many connections

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, reactive-programming, changestream

I have a Spring+MongoDB application and I set up an Auditing system using AsyncChangestreams that whatch only one field from only one collection.

So, whenever this field is updated or replaced, the watch sends a message to my application, then I get some infos from it and send them to an SQS. Simple as it is.

For this use-case I implemented only one repo as Reactive, meanwhile the rest of the already-running application is non-Reactive.
Everything works as expected but the fact that, once deployed in dev environment, the connections towards the Database skyrocket. In one hour they reached +1K.

I saw this isn't an uncommon problem, still I haven't found the solution to tune correctly the non-Reactive configuration.
The maxPoolSize wouldn't solve the number of Pools generated and I'm afraid a timeout on the creation of the ChangeStream would cause infinite loops in case of issues (also, I'm not sure how to properly set them in my configs).

My Reactive Repo:

```
@Component
public interface SomeCoolNameReactiveRepository extends MongoRepository<MyCollection,String> {

}
```

My StreamListener Container:

```
public class MongoStreamListenerContainer extends DefaultMessageListenerContainer {

    public MongoStreamListenerContainer(MongoTemplate template, ErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        super(template, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15), errorHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAutoStartup() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

ContainerConfig:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.mongodb.repository.SomeCoolNameReactiveRepository")
public class MongoStreamListenerConfig extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
    String databaseUrl;

    @Bean
    MessageListenerContainer changeStreamListenerContainer(MongoTemplate template, MongoMessageListener consentAuditListener,
                                                           ErrorHandler errorHandler) {

        MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer = new MongoStreamListenerContainer(template, errorHandler);

        ChangeStreamRequest<MyDocument> request =
                ChangeStreamRequest.builder(consentAuditListener)
                        .collection("my_collection")
                        .filter(newAggregation(match(
                                where("operationType").in("replace","update").
                                        and("my_collection.fieldToAudit").exists(true))
                        ))
                        .fullDocumentLookup(FullDocument.UPDATE_LOOKUP)
                        .build();

        messageListenerContainer.register(request, MyDocument.class, errorHandler);
        log.info("> Mongo Stream Listener is registered, database url: " + databaseUrl);
        return messageListenerContainer;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return new ConnectionString(databaseUrl).getDatabase();
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoClient reactiveMongoClient() {
        System.out.println("Creating mongo client..:  ");
        return MongoClients.create(createMongoClientSettings());
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveMongoTemplate reactiveMongoTemplate() {
        return new ReactiveMongoTemplate(reactiveMongoClient(), getDatabaseName());
    }

    private MongoClientSettings createMongoClientSettings() {
        log.info("Creating mongo client  " + databaseUrl);
        ConnectionString ConnectionString = new ConnectionString(databaseUrl);
        return MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(ConnectionString)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    ErrorHandler getLoggingErrorHandler() {
        return new ErrorHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleError(Throwable throwable) {
                log.error("Error in creating audit records {}", throwable.getMessage());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Listener where I receive the message from ChangeStream

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class MongoMessageListener implements MessageListener<ChangeStreamDocument<Document>, MyDocument> {

    @Autowired
    OtherNonReactiveRepositoryINeed otherNonReactiveRepositoryINeed;
    @Autowired
    QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate;

    @Value("${awsService.sqsAuditQueue}")
    String auditQueue;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message<ChangeStreamDocument<Document>, MyDocument> message) {

        OperationType operationType = message.getRaw().getOperationType();

        log.info("Operation type is : {}", operationType);

        log.info("Received Message in collection: {}, message raw: {}, message body:{}",
                message.getProperties().getCollectionName(), message.getRaw(), message.getBody());

        /* logic to send message to SQS

    }
}
```

Thank you so much in advance, any help / tip would be appreciated!